# How to write a word using nested loops?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I want to make a code that writes something when given a **specific list of numbers**. I *know* there is a another method by multiplying the string print statetement by each iteration, but I just did it this way.

```
numbers = [10 , 10 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 9 , 9 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 4]
for each_letter in numbers:
    output = ""
    for each_count in range(each_letter):
        output += "F"
    print(output)
```

```
This is the output


FFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFF
FFFF
FFFF
FFFF
FFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFF
FFFF
FFFF
FFFF
FFFF
```

The question is how can I extend this with spaces in between to form complete words using only the list of numbers?
For eg How can I write a whole word or a sentence?Is it even possible?

Open to suggestions ... ✌

Comment: To begin with, your program cannot display letters that do not start at the beginning of a line or have gaps (e.g., V).

Comment: Thanks -DVZ I didnt even think about that. But doesnt that mean that empty spaces between words cant be shown? If so is there any way I can show empty spots by editing my list of numbers? Could I do something like a another if statement that can print empty spaces in between for showing gaps.

I am a complete beginner so please dont judge me for doing something so basic and  messing up.

Comment: There may be more than one space (like in W or Q). The problem is way harder than you think.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over multiple lists together and print them like you did. For example:

```py
def make_row(count):
    r = ""
    for c in range(count):
        r += "F"
    r += " "*(10 - count) # comment this out to see what it does.
    return r

letter_f = [10 , 10 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 9 , 9 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 4]
letter_e = [10 , 10 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 9 , 9 , 4 , 4 , 10 , 10]

for letter_counts in zip(letter_f, letter_e):
    output = ""
    for letter_count in letter_counts:
        output += make_row(letter_count)
        output += "    "
    print(output)
```

BUT, I recommend you to change your way of representing letters. As @DYZ stated, you can't make all letters with this design.

Comment: Thanks Associa. I never looked it at that way